# My for loop returns the last value for all iteration in my python code

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I have a simple Python for loop that iterate throung an object field (4 product.price) and multiply it by a constant value

It prints the right calculated 4 values in the console, but when rendering it in the django template, all 4 results have the same value (the calculated value of the last iteration)

However with Return instead of Print it bring the following error
'float' object has no attribute 'get'

View

```
def reprice(request):
   list = Product.objects.all()
  ......
   for item in list:
        rp = item.price * value_USD
        print (rp)

   return render(request , 'multi/reprice.html', {'list' : list, 'rp' : rp })
```

template

```
      {% for item in list %}  
       {{ rp }}
       {% endfor %}
```

Comment: The line `rp = item.price * value_USD` overwrites the value of `rp` every loop. This is probably not what you want.

Answer (score 0):

Whatever values the variables contain when you call render() will be the values that arrive in Django.
Simply pass the data as you need it to appear when you are rendering it. No need to pass `rp`, just pass the list of values you want.

```
list = Product.objects.all()
return render(request, "multi/reprice.html", {"list": [item.price * value_USD for item in list]})
```

And then in Django:

```
{% for item in list %}  
{{ item }}
{% endfor %}
```